# Running query ask me for a Microsoft account

Tags: sql-server

I log well to a remote SQL Server 2008 R2 with the `sa` account hosted on a Windows 2008 R2.
I can see all my databases and their belonging tables.
But when I run queries, a popup is displayed asking me for a Microsoft account.
But as I am connecting with `sa` account I can't use a Microsoft account even a valid one belonging to the remote domain.
When I cancel I have the following error message:

> Unable to acquire authorization token
>   (Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.AzureAuthenticationManagement)

What should I do to run remotely my queries with the `sa` account ?

Comment: Had the same problem today. After reopening of Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio I could execute queries again.